# Quantlib match clean price with bbg clean price

Tags: fixed-income, bond, quantlib

I'm trying to match QL clean price with BBG clean price for POLGB 2.75 10/25/29 1029 priced for 15th of October 2021 for 2.5% yield. I'm not sure if my setup of bond is wrong or if there is a problem with precision of calculations.

```
import QuantLib as ql

todaysDate= ql.Date(15,10,2021)

ql.Settings.instance().setEvaluationDate(todaysDate)

issueDate = ql.Date(11, 2, 2019)
maturityDate = ql.Date(25, 10, 2029)
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Annual)
calendar = ql.Poland()
bussinessConvention = ql.Following
dateGeneration = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
monthEnd = False
schedule = ql.Schedule (ql.Date(25,10,2018), maturityDate, tenor, calendar, ql.Unadjusted,
                            ql.Unadjusted , dateGeneration, monthEnd)

dayCount = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA)
couponRate = .0275
coupons = [couponRate]

settlementDays = 0
faceValue = 100
fixedRateBond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlementDays, faceValue, schedule, coupons, dayCount)

print(round(fixedRateBond.cleanPrice(0.025,ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA),ql.CompoundedThenSimple,ql.Annual),6))
```

QuantLib clean price = 101.796832
BBG clean price  = 101.796834

Comment: Are you using the same settlement date? Can you post Bloomberg DES and YA for comparison please?

Comment: Yes, both settlement dates were the same for bbg and ql e.i 15th October 2021.  \

`POLGB 2 ¾ 10/25/29 ( PL0000111498 )
Spread    18.52bp  vs    8yPOLGB 2 ¾ 10/29
Price   101.796834                103.154 
Yield     2.5000000Wst        2.3147811  Ann
Wkout  10/25/2029@ 100.00                Yld7 7
Settle  10/15/21         10/15/21
Trade   10/13/21      Retro (Using input price)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BBG does not adjust dates when calculating NPV. To get the same result in QuantLib we need to add ql.Unadjusted to FixedRateBond parameter. Also to get exactly the same clean price we need to calculate dirty price and subtract rounded accrued amount.

```
fixedRateBond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlementDays, faceValue, schedule, coupons, dayCount, ql.Unadjusted)

print(round(fixedRateBond.dirtyPrice(0.025,ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISMA),
ql.Compounded,ql.Annual),6)-round(fixedRateBond.accruedAmount(ql.Date(15,10,2021)),3))
```

Quantlib clean price = 101.796834