# Quantlib match clean price with bbg clean price : Huge gap between calculated price and bloomberg

Tags: programming, quantlib

I am not able to make quantlib match bloomber price, maybe I don't use the right parameters into `ql.Schedule` or `ql.FixedRateBond`

I have a price of : 90.012 instead of 93.508 [Huge spread between my result and bloomberg]

**Below is the reproducible example :**

```
import QuantLib as ql

todaysDate= ql.Date(2,6,2023)

ql.Settings.instance().setEvaluationDate(todaysDate)

# Market conventions
calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond)
settlementDays = 2
faceValue = 100
compounding = ql.Compounded
compoundingFrequency = ql.Semiannual

# Bond schedule setup
issueDate = ql.Date(15, 5, 2019)
maturityDate = ql.Date(15, 5, 2029)
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)
schedule = ql.Schedule(issueDate, maturityDate, tenor, calendar, 
                    ql.Unadjusted, ql.Unadjusted, ql.DateGeneration.Backward, False)


# Bond parameters
rate = 3.5/100
dayCount = ql.Thirty360(ql.Thirty360.BondBasis)
bond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlementDays, faceValue, schedule, [rate], dayCount)

# YTM calculation
yieldRate = 4.767131/100  # YTM
yieldDayCount = ql.Thirty360(ql.Thirty360.BondBasis)
yieldCompoundingFrequency = ql.Semiannual
cleanPrice = bond.cleanPrice(yieldRate, yieldDayCount, compounding, 
                             yieldCompoundingFrequency, issueDate)

print("The clean price of the bond is: ", cleanPrice)
```

Bond DES and YASQ
[image]
[image]

Can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong ?

*Side Note :*

I have seen [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/68648/42110) but it seems that my issue is something else.

Comment: Why are you passing issueDate to bond.cleanPrice, nstead of the valuation date?

Comment: @DimitriVulis it seems that it is one of my mistake indeed, but I might have done some other mistakes since I don't match BBG price.

Comment: @DimitriVulis I think one of my other mistake is `compounding = ql.Compounded` wich should be `compounding = ql.SimpleThenCompounded` do you have an idea why ?

Comment: Did you reconcile your bond's cashflows between Quantlib and Bloomberg CSHF?